# PDO - Catch if any of these queries returns an empty result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using [Medoo](http://medoo.in/) (a PHP DB framework using PDO) with PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION enabled. I have some queries in a `try` and `catch` block and I want to throw an exception if any of those queries return an **empty result**.

PS: [$database->get()](http://medoo.in/api/get) is a simple PDO `SELECT` returning a single row. I don't think it's relevant and I think my example applies also to PDO without frameworks.

```
try {
    $q1 = $database->get(..);
    $q2 = $database->get(..);
    $q3 = $database->get(..);
    $q4 = $database->get(..);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die ("There was an error in a query.");
}
```

Right now I get into the `catch` block only if there is an error in the query, like I try to select a table that doesn't exist. I want to find the optimal way to avoid checking if every single query doesn't return an empty result manually, like I don't want to do this:

```
if (!$q1) { echo "No result"; }
if (!$q2) { echo "No result"; }
...
```

Is there a more generic approach?

Comment: if you want to catch an exception, you have to *throw* it first.

Comment: Doesn't this lead me to do it manually for every single query?

Comment: You have any other idea? You have a custom condition, for which you want an exception to be thrown. Either this or create another getOrFail() method based on get() to do it for you.

Comment: Turns out this meedoo thing is rather a swindle. It needs to be extended to be usable, and thus it cannot be called a usable smallest framework. Especially being a just primitive query builder. Besides, I fail to see where does it make PDO to throw exceptions.

Comment: @YourCommonSense it's terrible, that's the word, you're just too polite to call it for what it is. It's yet another "let's extend PDO and create something better but fail at it because it will suck more" type of class that for some reason became popular..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is wrong, an `Exception` is an event that occurs during program execution that disrupts normal flow.

Query that returns an empty result set is **not** disrupting normal flow of your program, because that query executed successfully.

If you think that it's a good idea to use exceptions in order to signal that an empty result is returned, you have to throw that exception.

[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent), which is an ORM used by Laravel contains a method called `firstOrFail` and `findOrFail` which perform what you're after.

Your option is to either create such a method for `Medoo` or use a proper ORM such as Doctrine or Eloquent that can help you achieve such behavior out of the box.